# How to access the executable file of the Android app through the /proc file system

Tags: android, linux, command, filesystems, kernel

I have my Android app and I need to access its executable (odex file) from my "non-rooted" device. I'm trying through accessing the process memory space by /proc. I'm getting the following result by /proc/self/maps

```
5e59c72000-5e59c9b000 r--p 00000000 fd:03 509                            /system/bin/toybox
5e59c9b000-5e59cde000 --xp 00029000 fd:03 509                            /system/bin/toybox
5e59cde000-5e59ce2000 rw-p 0006c000 fd:03 509                            /system/bin/toybox
5e59ce2000-5e59ce6000 r--p 00070000 fd:03 509                            /system/bin/toybox
5e59ce6000-5e59ceb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
715a800000-715b000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:libc_malloc]
715b10b000-715b10d000 r--p 00000000 fd:03 2578                           /system/lib64/libnetd_client.so
715b10d000-715b10f000 --xp 00002000 fd:03 2578                           /system/lib64/libnetd_client.so
715b10f000-715b110000 rw-p 00004000 fd:03 2578                           /system/lib64/libnetd_client.so
715b110000-715b111000 r--p 00005000 fd:03 2578                           /system/lib64/libnetd_client.so
715b111000-715b112000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:.bss]
715b161000-715b1c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:linker_alloc]
715b1c5000-715b1cc000 r--p 00000000 fd:03 2454                           /system/lib64/libcutils.so
715b1cc000-715b1d4000 --xp 00007000 fd:03 2454                           /system/lib64/libcutils.so
715b1d4000-715b1d5000 rw-p 0000f000 fd:03 2454                           /system/lib64/libcutils.so
715b1d5000-715b1d7000 r--p 00010000 fd:03 2454                           /system/lib64/libcutils.so
715b1d7000-715b1d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:.bss]
715b223000-715b229000 r--p 00000000 fd:03 2539                           /system/lib64/liblog.so
715b229000-715b237000 --xp 00006000 fd:03 2539                           /system/lib64/liblog.so
715b237000-715b238000 rw-p 00014000 fd:03 2539                           /system/lib64/liblog.so
715b238000-715b239000 r--p 00015000 fd:03 2539                           /system/lib64/liblog.so
715b239000-715b23a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:.bss]
715b249000-715b252000 r--p 00000000 fd:03 2406                           /system/lib64/libbase.so
715b252000-715b25b000 --xp 00009000 fd:03 2406                           /system/lib64/libbase.so
715b25b000-715b25c000 rw-p 00012000 fd:03 2406                           /system/lib64/libbase.so
715b25c000-715b25d000 r--p 00013000 fd:03 2406                           /system/lib64/libbase.so
715b25d000-715b25e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:.bss]
715b295000-715b296000 r--p 00000000 07:20 92                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libdl.so
715b296000-715b297000 --xp 00001000 07:20 92                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libdl.so
715b297000-715b298000 r--p 00002000 07:20 92                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libdl.so
715b298000-715b299000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:.bss]
715b2c7000-715b2d9000 r--p 00000000 07:20 93                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libm.so
715b2d9000-715b2fd000 --xp 00012000 07:20 93                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libm.so
715b2fd000-715b2fe000 rw-p 00036000 07:20 93                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libm.so
715b2fe000-715b2ff000 r--p 00037000 07:20 93                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libm.so
715b2ff000-715b300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [anon:.bss]
715b304000-715b344000 r--p 00000000 07:20 91                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so
715b344000-715b3eb000 --xp 00040000 07:20 91                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so
715b3eb000-715b3ee000 rw-p 000e7000 07:20 91                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so
715b3ee000-715b3f5000 r--p 000ea000 07:20 91                             /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so
```

I want to know whether we can get the memory addresses to where the executable file is loaded from this information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Posting what I learned here regarding solving the question. Below needs a rooted device. Android (after 5) uses JIT compiling so no odex files are actually created ( at least for small applications). When turned off JIT compiling and recompile the application ( going with the commands below in order), odex file memory location could indeed be found in /proc/self/maps.

```
adb root
adb shell stop
adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.usejit false
adb shell start
adb shell cmd package compile -m speed -f com.example.myapplication
```

Seems like we cannot use the shell start, shell stop commands without rooting. So not sure whether we can stop JIT compiling in non-rooted devices. However, absence of odex files is due to above.